# Old story where computer expert digitally animates The Lord of the Rings

Tags: story-identification, computers

Back in the 1960s there was a story about the head of a corporation in the late 20th or early 21st century who discovered that his computer expert was using the mainframe to digitally animate a version of The Lord of the Rings.  As I remember the image quality was supposed to equal that of realistic oil paintings.

Can anyone identify this story?

Answer (score 62, accepted):

## ["The Accomplice"](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?54197) (April 1967), by Vernor Vinge

> "The Accomplice"
>
> Originally published in *Worlds of If Science Fiction*, 1967.
>
> Bob Royce, CEO of Royce Technology, Inc., and his security officer Arnold Su have discovered that one of their employees has embezzled 4 million dollars worth of computer time. The evidence points to Howard Prentice, a 90-something renaissance man doing computer science research for the company. Prentice reveals that he has used the computers to create a 4-hour computer-generated film adaptation of J.R.R. Tolkien's The Lord of the Rings. This file is the culmination of a 30-year project by Prentice and his wife Moira to turn film into an art form which can be produced by individual artists.
>
> — Wikipedia: [*The Collected Stories of Vernor Vinge*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Collected_Stories_of_Vernor_Vinge#%22The_Accomplice%22)

The full issue of [*Worlds of IF* (April 1967)](https://archive.org/details/1967-04_IF/page/n117), including this story, is available to read online at the [Internet Archive](https://archive.org/about/).

Comment: A brilliant piece of SF predicting the future. But what else would you expect from Vinge?

Comment: @MarkOlson Does this mean there is a chance that we could solve NP problems (or harder) in polynomial time by venturing to the edge of the Galaxy?

Comment: @DavidTonhofer Maybe. Try it and let us know ;)

Comment: @MarkOlson - I think Vinge is awesome, but I don't know that there is going to be a single singularity moment as he seems to suggest.

Comment: @Mark Rogers Even Jove nods!

Comment: So... what parts of the Jackson films did they leave out?

Comment: @MarkRogers, Prediction is very difficult, especially about the future.